# Normal fit in easyGgplot2, kassambara

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

A need to superimpoze a normal fit on my histogram.
I haven't used a normal ggplot2, but I installed: "easyGgplot2" written by "kassambara". 
My data is the length of 250 men and 250 women.
This is what i have now:

```
plot <- ggplot2.histogram(data=mydata, xName='Lengte', 
                      binwidth=1, bins=10, 
                      scale="density",
                      groupName='Geslacht', 
                      groupColors = c("dodgerblue2","deeppink"),
                      alpha=0.3, 
                      #xlim=c(160,187),
                      position= "identity", 
                      densityFill='NONE')
```

[image: This is what I have so far, I still need the normal fits on it...]

Comment: you could add your dataset (using dput()) to your post. Why not simply use ggplot2? this could help you achieve what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450341/cant-fit-a-normal-curve-to-a-grouped-histogram/34451821#34451821

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Comment: to be honest not really cause I need to find it for my plot (and not for an normal ggplot with functions geom) but thanks already for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-histogram-easy-histogram-graph-with-ggplot2-r-package#histogram-plot-with-multiple-groups), the argument **addDensity = TRUE** is used for adding normal fit on the histogram.

Try the R code below:

```
library(easyGgplot2)
# Load data
data("weight")
head(weight)

# Histogram plots with normal fit
ggplot2.histogram(data=weight, xName='weight',
                 groupName='sex', legendPosition="top",
                 groupColors = c("dodgerblue2","deeppink"),
                 alpha=0.3, addDensity=TRUE)
```

[image: ggplot2 histogram sthda]

Good luck!

Comment: That may be a fit, but is is a normal fit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this? Just using `ggplot` as I am unfamiliar with `easyGgplot`. This estimates density:

```
library(ggplot2)

# average heights in cm
set.seed(1234)
avgFh <- 160
stdFh <- 6.1
nsampF <- 250
avgMh <- 173
stdMh <- 7.0
nsampM <- 250
xmin <- 150
xmax <- 190

hdf <- data.frame(height = c(rnorm(nsampF, avgFh,stdFh),rnorm(nsampM,avgMh,stdMh)))
muhat <-mean(hdf$height)
sdhat <-sd(hdf$height)
nsamp <- nrow(hdf)

# Plot Density
denarg <- list(mean = muhat, sd = sdhat)
tittxt <- sprintf("Height Density - Samples:%d Avg:%.1f Std:%.2f",nsamp,muhat,sdhat)

ggplot(hdf, aes(height)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins=30,fill="lightblue") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = denarg, size=2, col = 'blue') +
  labs(title=tittxt)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(xmin,xmax))
```

yielding this:

[image]

And if you want counts than this:

```
# Plot Count
f <- function(x){ nsamp*dnorm(x,muhat,sdhat)}
tittxt <- sprintf("Height Counts - Samples:%d Avg:%.1f Std:%.2f",nsamp,muhat,sdhat)

ggplot(hdf, aes(height)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..),bins=30,fill="lightgreen") +
  stat_function(fun =f, args = NULL, size=2, col = 'darkgreen') +
  labs(title=tittxt)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(xmin,xmax))
```

yields this:

[image]